# Marionette app 2 way navigation with history api

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, routes, marionette

I have node.js server application (rest API service).
I also have Backbone + Marionette(for my serverside RESTful app) multiple page app at the client side.
I currently have Marionette navigation which is work pretty good with links like [domain.com/#feedbacks](http://stackoverflow.com) (pages are render on client side with ajax data). But I also want to add serverside navigation e.g. [domain.com/feedbacks](http://stackoverflow.com) (for google and other seach engines).

The question is: **How can I match serverside and clientside navigations?**

Mb I should try to add event handler for all links on page, which is will do something like `Backbone.history.navigate("/feedbacks")`? But I have a lot different hash links(#feedbacks)... Mb there is a more elegant solution? Thank you.

My current marionette router:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Blazer.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      '': new HomeRoute(),
      'sell': new SellRoute(),
      'login': new LoginRoute(),
      'feedbacks': new FeedbacksRouter(),
      'product/:id': new ProductRoute(),
      'profile/:id': new UserRoute()
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to use:

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})
```

instead of:

```
Backbone.history.start();
```

It make backbone routing work without *#* symbols